# How can I export a csv file with multiple pandas dataframes stacked vertically?

Tags: pandas

Consider the dataframes below,

```
data_a = {'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data_a)

data_b = {'C':[7,8,9],'D':[10,11,12]}
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data_b)
```

I would like to export these two dataframes to a .csv file where they are stacked directly vertical to one another. If you do something like,

```
pd.concat([df_a,df_b],axis=0).to_csv('test.csv')
```

df_b will not be directly below df_a, it will be shifted to the right since it has different column names. How can I get them completely aligned with different header names?

Comment: So you want `df_b` column C to be under header A? Can you not just rename the columns of `df_b` to match those of `df_a`? Or do you want 2 headers and just do string concatenation of `df_a.to_csv()` with `df_b.to_csv()`? Can you give example output of what you expect with the example provided?

Comment: but then 'C' and 'D' won't be columns anymore? or do you want to keep just A and B and put all the values below?

Comment: Great questions, so I need the columns headers to be different, so literally different dataframes with different column names stacked exactly on-top of one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mode="a"` as append:

```
df_a.to_csv("test.csv", mode="w", index=False)
df_b.to_csv("test.csv", mode="a", index=False)
```

This creates `test.csv`:

```
A,B
1,4
2,5
3,6
C,D
7,10
8,11
9,12
```